# React-native scroll to top with pull to refresh iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a react-native app, that I want to scroll to top when the FlatList is refreshing in iOS. I can scroll to the top of the FlaList by using:

```
this.componentRef.FlatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
```

Now, the list has Pull-to-refresh on, so I would like to scroll above the refreshing indicator in iOS.

I tried:

```
this.componentRef.FlatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: -20, animated: true});
```

and declaring the RefreshControl with a ref  as refreshcontrol (using callback ref declaration):

```
this.componentRef.FlatList.refreshcontrol.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
```

and

```
this.componentRef.refreshcontrol.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
```

But none work. Is anyone aware of a way I can scroll above the refreshing indicator, if its on? This only happens in iOS as Android's refreshing indicator works differently.

**UPDATE:**

As scrollToOffset is not available for the RefrehControl component, it won;t work. Which brings me back to how can I scroll above a RefreshControl in a FlatList. My last attempt:

```
this.FlatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
```

Still scrolls to the beginning of the list, yet the "RefreshControl" is visually hidden.

I also tried adding an empty ScrollView above and scrolling to it, because it is empty, it did not work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

To clarify, this is how everything is called (simplified):

_scrollAndRefresh method in Main.js:

```
  _scrollAndRefresh = () => {
     this.setState({
       loading: true
     }, () => {
       this.CustomFlatList._scrollToTop();
     });
  }
```

Rendering the component in Main.js:

```
  <CustomFlatList ref={(ref) => {
      this.CustomFlatList = ref}}
    onRefresh={this._handleRefresh} loading={this.state.loading}/>
```

_handleRefresh method in Main.js:

```
  _handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, () => {
      // REFRESH ACTION
    })
  };
```

_scrollToTop method CustomFlatList.js:

```
  _scrollToTop = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && this.props.loading) {
      this.FlatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
    }
    else {
      this.FlatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
    }
  }
```

And FlatList CustomFlatList.js:

```
<FlatList
  ref={(ref) => { this.FlatList = ref; }}
  refreshControl={<RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.props.loading}
            onRefresh={this.props.onRefresh}
        />}
/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `<RefreshControl />` detect refresh behavior from gesture, `<FlatList />` scroll method has no effect on it; And you are just attempt to hack it.

Suggest to do it this way. You still scroll to top and shows refresh, and more directly:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    refreshing: false,
  }
}

/// scroll to top, and show refresh at the same time
scrollToTopAndRefresh() {
  this.componentRef.FlatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
  this.setState({
    refreshing: true,
  }, () => {
    this.refresh();
  });
}

refresh() {
  /// put your refresh logic here
}

componentRef = {};
render() {
  return (
    <FlatList ref={ (ref) => this.componentRef.FlatList = ref }
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={() => this.refresh()}
        />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

### Update 2:

I made a simple workable code for your needs.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Image,
    View,
    FlatList,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    RefreshControl,
} from 'react-native';

export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.scrollToTopAndRefresh = this.scrollToTopAndRefresh.bind(this);
        this.doRefresh = this.doRefresh.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            refreshing: false,
        }
    }

    scrollToTopAndRefresh() {
        this.flatlistref.scrollToOffset({y: 0, animated: true});
        this.setState({refreshing: true}, this.doRefresh);
    }

    doRefresh() {
        /// do refresh work here /////
        //////////////////////////////
        setTimeout( () => this.setState({refreshing: false}), 1000);
    }

    flatlistref = null;
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <FlatList
                    ref={(ref) => this.flatlistref = ref}
                    data={Array(30).fill(1)}
                    renderItem={() => <Text style={styles.line}>This is one line.</Text>}
                    refreshControl={
                        <RefreshControl
                            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                            onRefresh={this.doRefresh}
                        />
                    }
                />
                <Button title='Scroll To Top' onPress={this.scrollToTopAndRefresh} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    line: {
        height: 50,
        paddingTop: 17,
        textAlign: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'purple',
    }
});
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Where do you suggest I call scrollToTopAndRefresh()?

Comment: On my vacation, will reply at Monday

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it works on first click "Scroll To Top", but when the refresh controller disappeared, it won't work on the next click

Answer (score -1):

I have something like this in my app:

```
<FlatList
    refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
        />}
    data=...
/>
```

Maybe something like this would work:

```
this.componentRef.FlatList.scrollToOffset({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
this.setState({refreshing: true});
this._onRefresh();
this.setState({refreshing: false});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it doesn't scroll above the Refresh indicator, it goes only to the top of the flatlist